# Specify a secret in YML WITH a namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The example has:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: usernamekey
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: passwordkey
  restartPolicy: Never
```

the above from:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

I've created a secret like this:

```
kubectl --namespace=mycustomnamespace create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=passwordkey="abc123" --from-literal=usernamekey="mememe"
```

I understand that the above secrets exist under the namespace.

But if I try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
  namespace: mycustomnamespace
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: usernamekey
            namespace: mycustomnamespace
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: passwordkey
            namespace: mycustomnamespace
  restartPolicy: Never
```

(note that I added a namespace declaration under metadata)

I get this error:

> Error validating data:
>   [ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[1].env[2].valueFrom.secretKeyRef):
>   unknown field "namespace" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecretKeySelector,
>   ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[1].env[6].valueFrom.secretKeyRef):
>   unknown field "namespace" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecretKeySelector];

If I take out the namespace(s) (under the secretKeyRef(s))....the pod fails..with

> Warning  Failed     2s (x8 over 1m)  kubelet, minikube  Error:
>   secret "mysecret" not found

Yes, my secrets are in the namespace:

```
kubectl get secrets --namespace mycustomnamespace

NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
default-token-55bzp   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         10m
mysecret              Opaque                                2         10m
```

APPEND : (resolution)

It was an error on my part.  Check my comment under Vasily's answer.

But basically, the magic-sauce is that the below yml....

```
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
  namespace: mycustomnamespace
```

the above yml should "drive" the namespaces (aka, set the scope of the namespace) for the rest of the configuration (yml) ....

(if you are a future reader of this question, double and triple check that you have everything under the correct namespace.  ALL of your normal "get" statements need to use -n (aka --namespace) as a part.

example

```
kubectl get pods
```

the above will only get pods under "default".

you have to do

```
kubectl get pods --namespace mycustomnamespace
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove `namespace: mycustomnamespace` from pod secretKeyRef definitions.

Also your secret create command should be like that:

```
kubectl --namespace=mycustomnamespace create secret generic mysecret --from-literal=passwordkey="abc123" --from-literal=usernamekey="mememe"
```

Comment: I just appended my question text.  I get secret not found when I remove namespaces from under secretKeyRef(s). :( .  (Yes, I'll fix the secret creation code...that was "demo" copy/paste error).

Comment: can you paste the output of command "kubectl -n mycustomnamespace get secret"  and "kubectl -n mycustomnamespace get pod"?

Comment: Vasily, that request...helped me figure it out.  It was a configuration error on my part.  I'll mark this as correct.....future readers...........as Vasily showed me....make sure to do triple checks on pods,service,etc with the "-n" argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this You can run your pod

```
kubectl apply -f podconfigfile.yaml -n mycustomnamespace
```

This will run pod in the same namespace and find secret if the secret is created

If any error will be there then check for the namespace having secrets and proper name of the namespace.

Check secret in namespace :

```
kubectl get secret -n mycustomnamespace
```

Comment: Upvote for this "trick".  I did not know you can run "apply" with a -n argument.

Comment: You can use create and apply for any file and at the end give namespace so that particular file config will apply to namespace only.

Comment: for example creating service `kubectl apply -f service.yaml -n <namespacename>`